# Invalid floating point operation with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting An invalid floating point operation occurred error with this code.
It's telling me that the problem is on line where the CTE starts.
If I don't have the SQRT function, then everything work fine, but as soon as I add the SQRT I get the error.

What I'm trying to do is to get rid of the negative by squaring the number.

```
declare @start_date date, @end_date date
set @start_date = '2012/01/01' 
set @end_date = '2012/12/31';
with tbl1
as
(

    select 
        strata, 
        entranceID,
        sum(count)/count(*) as AverageCount
    from 
        train
    where 
        surveydate between '2012/01/01' and '2012/12/31'
    group by 
        strata, 
        entranceID
)
select 
    a.jobnumber,
    a.strata,
    a.EntranceID,
    Count,
    b.AverageCount,
    count - AverageCount
    , CASE WHEN AverageCount = 0 then 0
        ELSE SQRT(count - AverageCount)
        END as A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression:

```
SQRT(count - AverageCount)
```

The value of count  has to be >= AverageCount.

This may not be true for your test data.

Consider using :

```
SQRT (ABS(count - AverageCount))
```

Instead, If that makes sense in your case.

Comment: As you said that, I've discovered ABS function. Thank you